# Chrome.storage.onChanged store newValue when i click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

my content.js which i send token from web page with external_connectable 
and i set that token in background.js.My second content.js run other webpage and i call token which i set that token in background.js .  when token changed   i listen onChanged  method and  i give me newValue when i click button .
  when i click the button give me  newValue but My problem is when token is changed , again i click give 2 token old and new .when token changed again give 3 value .

p.s My english is bad sorry for that

content.js(send token to background.js ):

```
var x = localStorage.getItem("token");   
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("dcjcfafcmfgklldlfehalaedlaaboemo",{data: x });
```

backgrond.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
   if (request.data)

    chrome.storage.local.set({'token_data': request.data});

  });
```

content.js(second webpage call token ):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    $(".info-more").append($("<a class='my-button'></a>"));



     chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {

      $('.my-button').on('click',function(){

      console.log(changes.token_data);

    });  
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gives you more values because you are setting click handler each time for new message.

Just move the click handler outside the message listener:

2nd content.js:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    $(".info-more").append($("<a class='my-button'></a>"));

    var token;
    chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
        token = changes.token_data;
    });

    $('.my-button').on('click',function(){
        console.log(token);
    });  

});
```